# Visual Studio: Setup Project changes based on build configuration?

Tags: visual-studio, conditional-statements, project, installation

I have a project that was built for company X. Then they decided to allow company Y to use the product - and they wanted to make some minor branding-type changes. I come from a C programming background, so I added another build configuration that specifies a conditional compilation symbol depending on which brand the solution is being built for. Then the source code has a few:

```
#if COMPANY_X
  // do stuff
#elif COMPANY_Y
  // do different stuff
#endif
```

Now here's my question: Can I use the solution's build configuration to manipulate a single (Visual Studio Installer) setup project? Or do I have to maintain multiple setup projects to manage the differences between them (app name, install folder, manufacturer, etc.)? (Or perhaps more fundamentally, am I going about this all wrong?)

Background info: Visual Studio 2010, Visual Studio Installer, C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use single vs 2010 solution and create multiple solution configurations (ideally for different company or different environments).

VS 2010 Menu --> Build--> Configuration Manager--> Select new from Active solution configuration. Using this approach you dont have to write conditional builds.